# C : Splint pointers related warnings. What does they mean?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, splint

The following code compiles and execute without any warning or error. However, when I use [splint](http://www.splint.org/) to analyze the code, it shows 4 warnings (shown below the code).

Most of the examples I have seen (with that kind of warnings), uses malloc and free. As this code does not uses malloc, can we say its safe to ignore those warnings? What should be the correct way to code this without removing the pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    void (*Doit) ( void );
} func;

typedef struct
{
    func f;
    int val;
} obj;

typedef struct
{
    obj *o;
} world;

static void Read( void ) {
    printf( "Read\n");
}

static void Init( world *w ) {
    obj pc;
    w->o = &pc;           //(1)
    w->o->val = 10;
    w->o->f.Doit = Read;
    w->o->f.Doit();
}

int main() {
    world w;
    Init( &w );     //(2)
    return 0;      //(3)
}
```

> (1) :28:5: Implicitly only storage w->o (type obj *) not released before assignment: w->o = &pc . A memory leak has been detected. Only-qualified storage is not released before the last reference to it is lost.
>
> (1) :28:5: Immediate address &pc assigned to implicitly only: w->o = &pc . An immediate address (result of & operator) is transferred inconsistently.
>
> (2) :33:11: Variable w used before definition An rvalue is used that may not be initialized to a value on some execution path.
>
> (3) :34:14: Only storage w.o (type obj *) derived from variable declared in this scope is not released (memory leak). A storage leak due to incomplete deallocation of a structure or deep pointer is suspected. Unshared storage that is reachable from a reference that is  being deallocated has not yet been deallocated. Splint assumes when an object is passed as an out only void pointer that the outer object will be deallocated, but the inner objects will not.

This code is just a test of something else I want to achieve, but as I'm not proficient in C, I would like to understand the risk of memory leaks using the above approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though I took a C course a long time ago, I have to keep reading more in detail about memory management in C (I'm used to high level languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the `splint` output to be quite unreadable. Depending on your platform, you might also want to try `valgrind`.

Reglardless, the main issue with your code is that `pc` is a local variable.
It becomes invalid at the end of `Init()`, as it is (with probably every compilers) located on the stack.

You will probably want to do

```
w->o = (obj *) malloc(sizeof(obj));
```

instead.

An alternate way of doing this would be to change the type of o in w to `obj` instead of `obj *`.

**Note** on memory management in `C` (further reading highly recommended):

Function arguments and local variables usually lie on the so-called `stack`. They become invalid as soon as the function returns.
The size of stack objects always needs to be known to the compiler.

Objects that are allocated via `malloc()` lie on the heap. `malloc()` can be used for objects of unknown size. Objects allocated by `malloc()` stay valid until their pointers are passed to `realloc()` or `free()`. If you forget to pass a `malloc`'d pointer to `free`, you have a memory leak. If you access an object after it became invalid, you'll get undefined behaviour (that place in the heap might be re-used by something else by now, but maybe the data is still there, who knows?). In the worst case you might get a segmentation fault, or a heap corruption. If you pass an invalid object pointer to `free()` or `realloc()`, you'll probably get a heap corruption.

Global variables and static function members lie somewhere else (tm), and valid during the whole execution of the program (at least from entering main until returning from it, like a local variable of main).

`malloc()` is a complex function that internally manages available blocks of memory in a complex datastructure called the heap. A heap corruption means that you damage that datastructure itself. A segmentation fault means that you write/read somewhere outside of a valid block of memory.

Note that the `C` standard does not guarantee any if this. It doesn't guarantee that something like a stack even exists. However, all compilers that I know of do it like this. For some embedded platforms though, `malloc()` is a pretty simple function that just increments a pointer each time something is allocated, and `free()` does nothing at all.

Comment: Shouldn't malloc to be used if I don't know the size of the object at compile time? in this example, obj size is fixed to a pointer and an int size. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you very much! your explanation makes it very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

In Init()

```
static void Init( world *w ) {
    obj pc;
    w->o = &pc;           //(1)
    w->o->val = 10;
    w->o->f.Doit = Read;
    w->o->f.Doit();
}
```

obj pc; is a automatic variable in function Init().

The memory it is pointing will be invalid after retun from Init().
So In main() after Init() w->o will be invalid.

you have use malloc

```
w->o = (obj *) malloc(sizeof(obj));
```

you can do this in Init() or main().

Note: you  have to free this using free() else memory leak will occur.

Comment: "Have to" only if you're going to use `w->o` after `Init` returns. In the code in the question, it's not. If the question code is a simplified version of some real code, we can't tell whether it happens in that code.

Comment: So, as far as I don't use w->o after Init() its fine? What happen if I declare "obj pc" on main() and use the reference there instead? would that be fine?

Comment: you can move obj pc; w->o = &pc; lines to main(), then it should work

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help. After reading mice_e explanation now I understand it.